# Strategies to reverse engineer an RLE compression algorithm

Tags: compression, reverse-engineering

I tried to hack my way in the RLE stream with a Python script, but so far have not been lucky. The stream is not a *Packbits* stream, or any 'documented' RLE stream I could find.

Is there any known strategy that I could try to find my way in this binary stream ?

In fact, I'm trying to decipher the contents of some `.fpc` files that I have been given, which are created by *TerraExplorer* software, but I could not find any specification for the format. I do not own the software so I can't compress my own files.

These files are 'compressed' archive files containing one OpenFlight `.flt` 3d model files and several associated textures.

So far, I've been able to locate the individual files in the archive, but the files seem to be RLE compressed and cannot be read by traditional software.

I have access to some uncompressed files, but not their compressed counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you can try a bwt or a mft sorting. When there is a dictionary you can try all sorts of RLE and then a reverse bwt or mft to decipher the file.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure to follow you ; do you mean apply a bwt or a mft sorting to my already RLE compressed stream ? Could you please elaborate a little ?

Comment: No, I mean try to identify how many chars is used. And then after you decompress with rle you can check against bwt or mft. I mean finding all versions of RLE isn't really hard compared to a tsp problem?

Comment: Sorry I still don't follow you, as I don't know the RLE encoding, I can't decompress it. As of finding all versions of RLE, as tsp solving is quite outside my current field of expertise, I don't have a clue on how I could proceed...

Comment: @rotoglup: Maybe it's a Golomb code: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb-Code? Can you ask in encode forum: http://encode.ru? Maybe they can help you there?